# SVG hide an object until needed

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm able to move an object along a Bezier Curve but am having some difficulty with 'defs' and 'use'. My object (circle) appears at 0,0 before the animation begins, then appears in the correct position.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 300" style="border:1px solid black; width:500; height:500;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <path id="track" d="M100,200 C200,150 300,250 400,200" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <circle id="circ1" r="10" cx="0" cy="0" fill="red" >
    <animateMotion begin="1s" dur="6s" fill="freeze">
      <use href="#circ1" cx="100" cy="200"/>
      <mpath xlink:href="#track"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

How can I make it appear at the beginning of the Bezier line, not at 0,0?

Comment: Thank you for that, but my circle still appears at a new 0.0 before the animation begins.

Comment: The title of your question implies you want to hide the circle until the animation begins, but then the body states you want to place it at the beginning of the line. Can you clarify your desired result?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<set>` elements to set the position of the circle at the begining of the curve. Next at 1s you need to set again the position of the circle on 0,0

```html
<svg viewBox="0 50 500 300" style="border:1px solid black; width:500; height:300;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <path id="track" d="M100,200 C200,150 300,250 400,200" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <circle id="circ1" r="10" cx="0" cy="0" fill="red">
    <set begin="0" attributeName="cx" to="100" />   
    <set begin="0" attributeName="cy" to="200" />
    <set begin="1s" attributeName="cx" to="0" />    
    <set begin="1s" attributeName="cy" to="0" />
    <animateMotion begin="1s" dur="6s" fill="freeze">
      <!--<use href="#circ1" cx="100" cy="200"/>-->
      <mpath xlink:href="#track"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Yet another solution would be changing the origin of the curve so that it begins in the 0,0.

Please observe that I've changed the value of the viewBox attribute so that you can still see the curve in the middle of the svg canvas.

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -150 500 300" style="border:1px solid black; width:500; height:300;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <path id="track" d="M0,0C100,-50,200,50,300,0" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <circle id="circ1" r="10" cx="0" cy="0" fill="red" >
    <animateMotion begin="1s" dur="6s" fill="freeze">
      <!--<use href="#circ1" cx="100" cy="200"/>-->
      <mpath xlink:href="#track"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sean, your solution using <set> worked perfectly. I had not seen or used this before so a good learning experience! Thanks a bunch eh!